# Can SSI Injection or LDAP Injection be logged in web log?

Tags: ldap, security, ssi

Whether SSI Injection or LDAP Injection is visible in default web server log files (e.g. Apache , IIS) or not ? (Please provide some examples if possible)

In other words, can SSI Injection or LDAP Injection be logged in web log? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Anything can be logged.  The only question is whether or not you have something in place to actually detect it.